# how to select slicer value in excel

Tags: java, excel, vba, encoding, rpa

I am newbie with VBA and need to learn how to change automatically the selected values on a Slicer.Here in my excel having mulitple sheets and i need to select specific slicer value in the excel.

in my excel sheet1,sheet2 2 sheets are there in sheet2 having slicer name: slicer_bot1 is having fields gender .how to select particular value in slicer.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use the 'record macro' function. If it does not tell you exactly what object to use, hit F2 to view the object model or google the object to get all the information you need.